# Assymptotic approximation of $\int x^n \log xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Hi I'm following an Analysis course and one of the exercises is to prove that:

1. $$\int_{1/2}^1 x^n \log x dx \approx -1/n^2 $$
2. $$\left|\int_0^{1/2} x^n \log x dx\right| = O\left((1/2)^n\right)$$

At first I thought to solve this by the laplace method and write the integrand as a power of $e$ and then simplified by Taylor series.

Is there someone who can help me so that I will understand how to solve this asymptotic approximation.
Many thanks!!

Comment: Integration by parts might be helpful.

Comment: Hi Paul from my teacher I understood to solve this on another way than i tegration by parts. Which method can I use than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral can be evaluated in closed form.  Integrating by parts, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b x^n \log x\,dx&=\left.\frac{x^{n+1}\log x}{n+1}\right|_a^b-\frac{1}{n+1}\int_a^bx^n\,dx\\\\
&=\left.\frac{x^{n+1}\log x}{n+1}\right|_a^b-\left. \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}\right|_a^b\\\\
&=\frac{b^{n+1}\log b-a^{n+1}\log a}{n+1}-\frac{b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}
\end{align}$$

Setting $a=1/2$ and $b=1$ for Part $1$ and setting $a=0$ and $b=1/2$ for Part $2$ yield the desired results.

---

Suppose one is not permitted to use integration by parts at this stage.  Then for the integral $\int_a^b x^n \log x\,dx=\int_a^b e^{n\log x}\,\log x\,dx$, we can write (in the spirit of [Laplace's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method#The_idea_of_Laplace.27s_method))

$$\log x \sim  \log b +\frac1b(x-b)$$

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b e^{n\log x}\,\log x\,dx &\sim \int_a^b e^{n\log b+\frac{1}{b}(x-b)}\left(\log b+\frac{n}{b}(x-b)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{b^{n+1}\log b}{n}\left(1-e^{-n(b-a)/b}\right)-\frac{b^{n+1}}{n^2}\int_0^{n(b-a)/b}\,te^{-t}\,dt\tag 1
\end{align}$$

whereupon applying the specific value for $a$ and $b$, we can deduce the asymptotic limiting behavior without integrating by parts the integral in $(1)$.

Comment: Hi Dr. MV thank you for your help. Is there also another way to proof this without using integration by parts. Because I understood from our teacher that we must not use integration by parts for this problem.

Comment: You're welcome. My pleasure.  What are you permitted to use?  What topics are you studying?

Comment: Hi Dr. MV but if n-> infinity then both parts will go to zero?

Comment: I'm following a pre master course math and one of  topics is analysis. In this course we handled for assymptotic approximations the laplace method, integration by parts. We handled as topic Stirling.

Comment: To address your first comment ... Yes, both parts go to zero.  That is consistent with the answers you wrote in the OP.

Comment: Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions, but how can I proof that if n-> infinity that the integral between the boundaries of 1/2 and zero will be approximately -1/n^2 and on the interfall 0 and 1/2 O((1/2)^n) if both parts in the result you shows goes to zero

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you also explain why the integral under nr 2 in my question has been put between absolute sign?

Comment: The integrand is negative.  So, the absolute value signs makes the result of opposite sign.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Hello I'm still struggling with the integral under nr. 2 how to proof that the integral between 0 and 1/2 is approximately O((1/2)^n). Can anyone help me.

Comment: Recall that $(1/2)^{n+1}=O((1/2)^n)$ and also $(1/2)^n/n=O((1/2)^n)$.

Comment: Sorry can you do it step by step and what does the $ mean is this an integral sign?

Comment: Where did you see a $ sign?  I don't understand.

Comment: In your reply on my question for O. T $(1/2)^(n+1)=O((1/2)^n)$....

Comment: Well, I don't see a dollar ($) symbol there.

Comment: It is I think a print mistake on my screen. Anyway I don't still understand how I can proof step by step that the integral under nr 2 is by approximation O((1/2)^n) By using the laplace method. Can you help me with that. So I will understand this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I provided a proof using a way forward that is similar to Laplace's Method.  But since $f(x) =\log(x)$ does not have a local maximum, we have to keep the linear term.  Note that for $b=1/2$, the term in equation $(1)$ that decays most slowly is $(1/2)^{n+1}\log (1/2)/(n+1)$.  And this term is big O of $(1/2)^n$ by the definition of big O.

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for so far . I'm first going to look by myself If I do understand. what you explained. So for tihis moment many thanks again for your help and quick response!!

Comment: Of course.  Always my pleasure.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $~F(n)=\displaystyle\int x^n~dx,~$ then $F'(n)=\displaystyle\int x^n\ln x~dx$.